# Kafka Streams consumer groups concurrency: consuming from one partition only?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, apache-kafka-streams

I have an AWS infrastructure of

- 1 Kafka cluster on 3 docker containers, running on ECS, using EFS as storage service (for simplicity).
- 1 Kafka Streams application cluster, on 3 containers.

There is a source topic "events" with 16 partitions, replication 2. A PAPI topology processor "stream-processor" produces output to some other topics and uses 3 state stores.

I can see via Kafka Manager that data is consumed, and output is produced to these other output topics. Apparently it works (though slow).

But looking at consumer offsets via *bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh*, I can see that **only one of the partitions is being consumed simultaneously** over time. In separated, consecutive runs of the command, only one of the offsets is reduced.

First execution:

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                          HOST            CLIENT-ID
events          6          -               4021552         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          13         5030392         5030541         149             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          2          7056462         7056462         0               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          8          671945          6046546         5374601         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          1          164123          3009191         2845068         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          12         1962842         11052506        9089664         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          5          -               4022059         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          0          -               4019992         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          4          -               5032053         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          11         5037439         5037584         145             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          15         1683056         5034689         3351633         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          7          164702          7052434         6887732         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          14         -               3011069         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          3          1927601         6044400         4116799         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          10         5031461         5031612         151             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          9          1686979         8052924         6365945         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
```

Second execution: Only the partition 8 has advanced its offset. After 1, 5 or 15 minutes, that one is the only partition consumed.

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                          HOST            CLIENT-ID
events          6          -               4021552         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          13         5030392         5030541         149             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          2          7056462         7056462         0               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          8          686685          6046546         5359861         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          1          164123          3009191         2845068         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          12         1962842         11052506        9089664         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          5          -               4022059         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          0          -               4019992         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          4          -               5032053         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          11         5037439         5037584         145             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          15         1683056         5034689         3351633         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          7          164702          7052434         6887732         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          14         -               3011069         -               stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          3          1927601         6044400         4116799         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          10         5031461         5031612         151             stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
events          9          1686979         8052924         6365945         stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer-6cc2 /same.ip.here  stream-processor-fa36-StreamThread-1-consumer
```

Looking at the logs, only one of the instances is printing logs at the same time. I.e. if one is working, the other two are not.

What could be the problem here?

Kafka & Kafka Streams versions 1.1.

Comment: Not sure what might be the issue. What irritates me, is that the "client-id" is the same for all partitions. If you have 3 application instances, there should be 3 different clientIds (or did you miss configure your containers and do not assign a different client-id per container? The whole purpose of the client-id is to make them unique to be able to distinguish different instances)

Comment: Apparently, the two other application instances had not broken, but their KafkaStreams object had been closed. So, the only running instance took care of all the partitions. Guess that makes sense. There was a bug in my exception handling that allowed that. Now seems fine, exception gets handled better, and the application after the KafkaStreams is closed.

Comment: Separately, about task parallelism - so in the depicted situation, if the only living KafkaStreams object remains, and it is configured with numThreads=1, what is the expected outcome? "There is 1 Task, which is processing a partition, and (the same task) will not start with another partition until it reduces lag to 0"? How can you control that other partitions don't lag too much meanwhile others get processed - is there nothing else to do than add as many threads as partitions are?

Comment: If there is only one instance with one thread, it should read data for all tasks and make progress for all tasks in parallel. I have no explanation atm why you see a different behavior. Having said this, I am not sure if I follow the question completely. Note, that the consumer will fetch data from all partitions in round-robin manner. If the first poll() call return data from only one partitions, that this data will be processed before the next poll() call is made (which will return data for the next partition).

Comment: What factors determine how long it takes to do the next poll? It sounds strange that time between polls takes so long, doesn't it?

Comment: It's your custom processing logic, and config `max.poll.records` consumer config (set to 1000 in Kafka Streams by default). You might want to look into metrics to see where the time goes: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html